# How to add hyphen between characters in a string, creating a new string as the result

Tags: java, string

This is my method. It doesn't return anything. Please help, I don't know how  to get the desired String name longer (the initial word string with hyphens between characters). `

```
public static String stretch(String word){

    String longer = "" + word.charAt(0);

    for (int i=1; i<=word.length()-1; i++){
        longer += "-" + word.charAt(i);
    }

    return longer;
}
```

Comment: Huh?  Not a clue what you are asking.  Please show expected input and output.  THanks.

Comment: You want to run `stretch("sample string")` and return `"s-a-m-p-l-e- -s-t-r-i-n-g"`?

Answer (score 2):

Below are three different ways of achieving your desired result, they are in ascending order in terms of performance + simplicity to understand i.e. `stretch3` **>** `stretch2` **>** `stretch1`.

```
import java.util.StringJoiner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(stretch("test"));
    System.out.println(stretch2("test"));
    System.out.println(stretch3("test"));
  }

  // Using String Concatenation (bad)
  public static String stretch(String word) {
    String longer = "" + word.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
      longer += "-" + word.charAt(i);
    }
    return longer;
  }

  // Using StringBuilder (good)
  public static String stretch2(String word) {
    StringBuilder longer = new StringBuilder(word.substring(0,1));
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) {
      longer.append("-" + word.charAt(i));
    }
    return longer.toString();
  }

  // Using StringJoiner (best)
  public static String stretch3(String word) {
    StringJoiner longer = new StringJoiner("-");
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
      longer.add(word.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    return longer.toString();
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
t-e-s-t
t-e-s-t
t-e-s-t
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/repls/CyberThornyLicenses)

Answer (score 1):

Try if you want to insert a hyphen between letters (and not words)

```
"test sample".replaceAll("\\w(?=\\w)", "$0-");
```

Output -> `t-e-s-t s-a-m-p-l-e`